# GUI showing but not functional

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have to write some Java code to create GUI and the idea is this. The user will input two numbers and then he will choose one of the radiobuttons. If he chooses "zgjidh", he should click a button that will do the calculations depending on what kind of calculation the button is for. "Fshij"button is kinda like reset to clear all field. If he chooses "dil" the window will close. For some reason it doesn't seem to work. Can someone help me?

```
   import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
   import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
   import javax.swing.*;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Gui extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
  JButton plus,minus,fshi;
  JTextField vn1,vn2,vrez;
  JLabel n1,n2,rezultati;
  JRadioButton zgjidh,dil;
  ButtonGroup grupi;

  public Gui(){
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JPanel veri=new JPanel();
    veri.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));

    n1=new JLabel("Jep numrin e 1");
    veri.add(n1);

    vn1=new JTextField(10);
    veri.add(vn1);

    n2=new JLabel("Jep numrin e 2");
    veri.add(n2);

    vn2=new JTextField(10);
    veri.add(vn2);

    rezultati=new JLabel("Rezultati");
    veri.add(rezultati);

    vrez=new JTextField(10);
    veri.add(vrez);

    add(veri,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JPanel qender=new JPanel();
    qender.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

    zgjidh=new JRadioButton("Zgidh Veprimin");
    zgjidh.addActionListener(this);
    dil=new JRadioButton("Dil");
    dil.addActionListener(this);
    grupi=new ButtonGroup();

    grupi.add(zgjidh);
    grupi.add(dil);

    qender.add(zgjidh);
    qender.add(dil);

    add(qender,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel jug=new JPanel();
    jug.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
    plus=new JButton("+");
    plus.addActionListener(this);
    jug.add(plus);

    minus=new JButton("-");
    minus.addActionListener(this);
    jug.add(minus);

    fshi=new JButton("Fshij");
    fshi.addActionListener(this);
    jug.add(fshi);

    add(jug,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

  }
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){ 
    double n1=Double.parseDouble(vn1.getText());
    double n2=Double.parseDouble(vn2.getText());
    if (e.getSource()==zgjidh) {
        if (e.getSource()==plus) {
            vrez.setText(""+(n1+n2));
        }
        else if (e.getSource()==minus) {
            vrez.setText(""+(n1-n2));
        }
        else if (e.getSource()==fshi) {
            vn1.setText("");
            vn2.setText("");
            vrez.setText("");
        }
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==dil) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Gui ob=new Gui();
    ob.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ob.setSize(500,500);
    ob.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: "For some reason it doesnt seem to work." You unfortunately forgot to tell us what exactly does not work. What do you expect? What happens instead? Additionally, if _something does not work_, you should start to debug your program.

Comment: Gui inerface shows but it's not functional, nothing will work, when i click on radiobutton and buttons to do the calculations nothing happens

Comment: I believe there must be something wrong with the radio buttons or buttongroup but cant seem to find it

Comment: Quote from my myself: "Debug your program"!

Comment: Please edit the question to add additional information  (do not use comments for this purpose).

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix it. This is the modified code

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
    double n1=Double.parseDouble(vn1.getText());
    double n2=Double.parseDouble(vn2.getText());
    if (zgjidh.isSelected()) {
        if (e.getSource()==plus) {
            vrez.setText(""+(n1+n2));
        }
        else if (e.getSource()==minus) {
            vrez.setText(""+(n1-n2));
        }
        else if (e.getSource()==fshi) {
            vn1.setText("");
            vn2.setText("");
            vrez.setText("");
        }
    }
    else if(dil.isSelected()) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```